# TypeScript Narrow Enum Type without Casting (Redux)

Tags: typescript

I want to type my redux actions more efficiently. At the moment I declare my actions in the class `Actions` and narrow down the action type explicitly. That way typescript will narrow down the type of `action` in the reducer and I can see there which type `action.payload` has which is good.

But I want to get rid of the explicit casting `<ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE>ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE`. Can it be done more generic / easier/ shorter?

```
export enum ActionTypes {
    INCREMENT_BY_ONE = 'INCREMENT_BY_ONE',
    INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE = 'INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE',
}

class Actions {
    incrementByOne() {
        return {
            type: <ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE>ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE,
        };
    }
    incrementByMultiple(multiple: number) {
        return {
            type: <ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE>ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE,
            payload: multiple,
        };
    }
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export type KnownAction = ReturnType<ValueOf<Actions>>;

function reducer(state, action: KnownAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE:
            // Property 'payload' does not exist on type { type ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE; }.
            const a = action.payload; 
            break;
        case ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE:
            // payload: number
            const b = action.payload;
            break;
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nngwzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell TypeScript to narrow down the type as far as it can. You can only do this explicitly - but there is a nice way to tell TypeScript to do exactly that.

```
class Actions {
    incrementByOne() {
        return {
            // Typecast using const, this tells TypeScript to narrow down the type to the most specific one, which is ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE
            type: <const>ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE, 
        };
    }
    incrementByMultiple(multiple: number) {
        return {
            type: ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE as const, // Alternatively using 'as' syntax
            payload: multiple,
        };
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can mark the whole Action as const - the benefit being that all properties will also be marked as readonly. Which is something you usually want with Action.

```
class Actions {
    incrementByOne() {
        return <const> {
            type: ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_ONE, 
        };
    }
    incrementByMultiple(multiple: number) {
        return {
            type: ActionTypes.INCREMENT_BY_MULTIPLE,
            payload: multiple,
        } as const; // Alternatively using 'as' syntax
    }
}
```

And here the [Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fersdm)